# Pass only the arguments I want in a function

Tags: c#, function, arguments

Suppose I have a function like that:

```
public void Set(int a, string b, char c, float d, int e, float f, string g){
    //do something with a
    //do something with b
    //...
    //do something with g
}
```

I need to do only some of these things, based on the arguments I want to send to the function. The rest should be ignored.

For example: `Set(a: 1, c: 'x', f: 1.4f, g: "hello")`. Only the arguments I sent must be taken in account, the rest should just be ignored. How can I write such function that behaves like this?

---

Right now I'm passing a `Dictionary<string, object>` to the function and asking "Do you contain this key?  If you do, execute something with its value", but I'd like to know if it's possible this way I'm asking, as it looks cleaner.

Comment: [Optional Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments)? You could do `void Set(int? a = null, string b = null, char? c = null,...)`. Then, inside the method, you just check if  they have values: `if (a.HasValue) { /* do something with a */ } if (b != null) { /* do something with b */ }...`

Comment: How can you just not pass some of the arguments? Doesn’t your method need them?

Comment: Rather than take multiple parameters take one. That will be of type `Bob` and it can have a constructor setup however you'd like (some mandatory constructor parameters, some optional etc etc).

Comment: @JohnWu it's not a problem for me to do some testing to see if the argument was received or not, I just want to be able to call the function with a custom set of parameters because some of them must be updated and some don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can use a `Dictionary<string, dynamic>` : thus you can check the keys to have typed arguments.

```
public void Set(Dictionary<string, dynamic> data)
{
  if ( data.ContainsKey("a") )
    Console.WriteLine(data["a"]);
}
```

You can also use nullable parameters and if null you don't manage them:

```
public void Set(int? a, string b, char? c, float? d, int? e, float? f, string g)
{
  if ( a.HasValue ) Console.WriteLine(a); // also a.Value
}
```

I prefer this last that is more clean and robust.

With optional parameters:

```
public void Set(int? a = null, string b = null, char? c = null, float? d = null, int? e = null, float? f = null, string g = null)
{
}

Set(e: 10);
```

Comment: The second one won't let you pass only some parameters. They need to be [optional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments) (i.e., have a default value).

Comment: The third option is what I needed, worked just fine, thanks.